# Display inside loop along with flush fuction in Java using swing

Tags: java, swing, loops, display, flush

Hey guys I was trying to program the dinosaur game of google chrome in swing. I have got everything read(the graphics of the surrounding and the dinosaur) but I am having problem to display(couldnt run loops in swing). I could run the program with the desired results on the normal java display mode with sopln, however it was in the swing that I was having a problem. I tried swingwoker class but couldn't get to creat JTextArea. Even though I didnt write JTextField anywhere on the entire program, the display is only comming in a JTextField kind of space. Can I display in swing using loops in a JTextArea in a normal way with the flush fuction(\f) to make the game?

Comment: please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/conduct and please provide your work, code, what you had acheived yet

Comment: For better help sooner please post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue.